# Restarting Android application that has been uploaded to Google Play Store

Tags: java, android

I created an Android application a few months back and uploaded it to the Google Play Store. Over the past few months I've had a lot of practice with Java and Android development; naturally, I decided to update my Android application with my new found knowledge. After exploration of my Android code I was horrified by how unorganized and sloppy my entire application was. I then decided it would be best for me to simply start the application from scratch - Create a new Android Studio project and develop a brand new app. Then it occurred to me the problems that might arise when signing the application and re-uploading it to the Google Play Store.

Can someone explain to me how I should go about re-creating an Android application I have already uploaded to the Play Store? Is this allowed or will I need to work with the current code I have?

Comment: As long as the package name is the same, you can update your existing apk with the new one.

Comment: What about signing the application?

Comment: Keep your version code higher, use same package id and sign with same .keystore.

Comment: And dont forget to make update test before publishing :D

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write the whole application. but if you want to update the application then you have to keep the same Package name which you use for the first time while uploading on play store. and also you need to change the version and version code. and in the end when you build signed APK you have to use the old Key store file which you use for the first time for building signed APK

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upload newly created app with same package then do this in your already uploaded apk :

**unpublish it & 
rename its package name from google play console.**

Now you can use same package name for your new app.
 Else you can change package name by setting application id in your **build.gradle** file you can set package name by module settings > select app > flavours tab > application id Now you can decide how you want upload your app.